# Rethinkdb mapreduce not has_fields not working properly

Tags: mapreduce, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm trying to find the percent of records (grouped by company) that do not have phone numbers. I can do this with the following two queries:

```
r.table('users') \
 .merge(lambda u: {'groups': r.table('groups').get_all(r.args(u['group_ids'])).coerce_to('array')}) \
 .filter(lambda u: u.has_fields('phone')) \
 .group(lambda u: u['groups'][0]['company']).count().run()
```

and to get the count of all records:

```
r.table('users') \
 .merge(lambda u: {'groups': r.table('groups').get_all(r.args(u['group_ids'])).coerce_to('array')}) \
 .group(lambda u: u['groups'][0]['company']).count().run()
```

However, I'd like to use map-reduce to do this in a single query and possibly be more efficient. Here is my query, but it doesn't work because both of the numbers (phone and count) are the same:

```
r.table('users') \
 .merge(lambda u: {'groups': r.table('groups').get_all(r.args(u['group_ids'])).coerce_to('array')}) \
 .group(lambda u: u['groups'][0]['company']) \
 .map(lambda u: { 'phone': 1 if u.has_fields('phone') else 0, 'count': 1 }) \
 .reduce(lambda a, b: {'phone': a['phone'] + b['phone'], 'count': a['count'] + b['count'] }).run()
```

So my question is, why doesn't `has_fields()` work in the `map` command, but does in the `filter` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Python's `if/then/else` operators.  Python doesn't expose a way to interact with these, so the driver can't see the whole `if/then/else` statement.  If you use `r.branch` instead (`r.branch(u.has_fields('phone'), 1, 0)`) it should work.

Comment: Ah OK... makes sense. Thanks!